# How can I setup a group writeable directory?

Tags: linux, permissions

```
$ whoami
meder
$ cd /var/www
$ sudo mkdir html
$ sudo groupadd web
$ sudo usermod -a -G web meder
$ sudo usermod -a -G web medertest
$ sudo chown meder:web html
$ sudo chmod -R g+rwx html
```

The problem is, anytime I create a new file in `/var/www/html` even though the group is set to `web`, it is only writeable by the original user.

I was given the advice of setting the `umask` to be `002` because the default is what causes the problems. But I would have to do this for *all* users in that group, and as far as I know it would be tedious having all of them modify `~/.bashrc` to have `umask 002`. Even if I can do it myself with a shell command for all of those users, it still seems too tedious.

Can anyone offer any advice on having a group writeable directory?

Comment: Have you tried logging out and then logging again with the user meder? Group information is not updated in the current session.

Comment: @marco - I did `su medertest` and `su meder` like a thousand times. Does that qualify as a log out?

Comment: @marco thanks did not know that group info is not updated in the current session... bummer

Answer (score 31, accepted):

First, enable the SGID bit on your directory:

```
sudo chmod g+s html
```

This will make new files created inside that directory inherit the parent's group ownership.

There is no inheritance of permission levels in the POSIX permission model. However, this can be done with [Access Control Lists](http://www.ghacks.net/2010/01/28/further-control-of-linux-files-with-acl/), without having to worry about umask settings:

```
sudo setfacl -d -m group:web:rwx html
```

It's a real bummer that umask cannot be assigned on a per-directory basis.

Comment: what's `g+s` in numbers?

Comment: @WearetheWorld prepend with 2: `chmod 2XXX file`.

Comment: I have been hunting around for this answer forever, and I just got referred to it via a Twitter response.  Thanks @mizo!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the setgid bit on the directory.

```
chmod g+s html
```

Comment: Can I combine this chmod with the `g+rwx` one?

Comment: @meder: yes `g+rwxs`

Comment: This only preserves directory ownership, not directory permissions.